# Notification never appears Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I'm using Kotlin and Android Studio to try and push a Notification in an app. I followed the instructions in the Android Developers site on How to create a Notification,but I seem to be doing something wrong as my Notification is not showing anywhere. Here's my code:

**UPDATE 2023-10-07**

Receiver class

```
class NotifierReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        val prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(AppUtils.USERS_SHARED_PREF, AppUtils.PRIVATE_MODE)
        val notificationsTone = prefs.getString(
            AppUtils.NOTIFICATION_TONE_URI_KEY, RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(
                RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION
            ).toString()
        )

        val title = context.resources.getString(R.string.app_name)
        val messageToShow = prefs.getString(
            AppUtils.NOTIFICATION_MSG_KEY,
            context.resources.getString(R.string.pref_notification_message_value)
        )


        val nHelper = NotificationHelper(context)
        @SuppressLint("ResourceType") val nBuilder = messageToShow?.let {
            nHelper
                .getNotification(title, it, notificationsTone)
        }
        nHelper.notify(1, nBuilder)

    }
}
```

BootReceiver

```
class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    private val alarm = AlarmHelper()

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent != null && intent.action != null) {
            if (intent.action == "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED") {
                val prefs = context!!.getSharedPreferences(AppUtils.USERS_SHARED_PREF, AppUtils.PRIVATE_MODE)
                val notificationFrequency = prefs.getInt(AppUtils.NOTIFICATION_FREQUENCY_KEY, 60)
                val notificationsNewMessage = prefs.getBoolean("notifications_new_message", true)
                alarm.cancelAlarm(context)
                if (notificationsNewMessage) {
                    alarm.setAlarm(context, notificationFrequency.toLong())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AlarmHelper

```
class AlarmHelper {
    private var alarmManager: AlarmManager? = null

    private val ACTION_BD_NOTIFICATION = "NOTIFICATION"

    fun setAlarm(context: Context, notificationFrequency: Long) {
        val notificationFrequencyMs = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(notificationFrequency)

        alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

        val alarmIntent = Intent(context, NotifierReceiver::class.java)
        alarmIntent.action = ACTION_BD_NOTIFICATION

        val pendingAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            0,
            alarmIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )

        Log.i("AlarmHelper", "Setting Alarm Interval to: $notificationFrequency minutes")

        alarmManager!!.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis(),
            notificationFrequencyMs,
            pendingAlarmIntent
        )

        /* Restart if rebooted */
        val receiver = ComponentName(context, BootReceiver::class.java)
        context.packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
        )
    }

    

    fun checkAlarm(context: Context): Boolean {

        val alarmIntent = Intent(context, NotifierReceiver::class.java)
        alarmIntent.action = ACTION_BD_NOTIFICATION

        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context, 0,
            alarmIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        ) != null
    }
}



    fun notify(id: Long, notification: NotificationCompat.Builder?) {
        if (shallNotify()) {
            getManager()!!.notify(id.toInt(), notification!!.build())
        }
    }

    private fun getManager(): NotificationManager? {
        if (notificationManager == null) {
            notificationManager = ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        }
        return notificationManager
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
if (!alarm.checkAlarm(requireContext()) && notificStatus) {
                alarm.setAlarm(
                    requireContext(),
                    sharedPref.getInt(AppUtils.NOTIFICATION_FREQUENCY_KEY, 30).toLong()
                )
            }
```

Comment: share your manifest.xml check for permissions and make sure u register the receiver

Comment: @HezyZiv posted

Comment: Please reduce the question's code to the bare minimum needed to reproduce the problem

Comment: @CliffBurton I updated, it seems that checkAlarm always returns true and that notifications are never set